# Modified Tukey window applied in frequency domain

Tags: filters, window-functions

In analysis of transient signals (ground motion time-series) in seismology, many operations are performed in frequency domain and it is common practice to apply a filter which is like a modified Tukey window in frequency domain to keep data band-limited before applying an inverse IFFT to go back to time-domain. Essentially, 4 frequencies `f1`, `f2`, `f3` and `f4` are specified and the filter is a combination of high pass and low pass taper. Here quoting from a web manual- 
"The taper is unity between `f2` and `f3` and `zero` below `f1` and above `f4`. Frequencies `f1` and `f2` specify the high-pass filter at low frequencies, while frequencies `f3` and `f4` specify the low-pass filter at high frequencies. Both `f3` and `f4` should be less than the Nyquist frequency: `0.5/DELTA`. The filters applied between `f1` and `f2` and between `f3` and `f4` are quarter cycles of a cosine wave. To avoid ringing in the output time series, a suggested rule-of-thumb is `f1 = f2/2` and `f4 >= 2*f3`".

Can someone please explain what is the reason behind the rule of thumb mentioned at the end ?
Is there any specific advantage of using such a filter compared to other filters like an acausal Butterworth filter ?

I have added links to 2 figures (for some reason, upload image is not working for me) which show time and frequency domain response of 4 filters (cosine tapers with `f2=2f1` and `f4=2f3` [black], and `f2=1.25f1` and `f4=1.25f3` [red] with `f2=0.2 Hz` and `f3=0.9 Hz`) and 2-pass bandpass Butterworth filters with 4 and 8 poles applied at frequencies `f2` and `f3`.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the 2:1 frequency ratio recommendation for the transition band (f2:f1 or f4:f3):

The steeper the filter response (i.e. the smaller the frequency ratio between pass band and stop band limits), will necessarily produce a much longer impulse response and produce ringing artifacts in the time domain whenever there is a transient.

These filters, which are applied in the frequency domain, also seem to have linear phase response, which is very desirable for analysing this type of signal.

Butterworth filters have a compact and nice representation as difference equations (for filtering in the time domain), but do not have linear phase response, and as you see from your plots, have not very good transition between pass band and stop band.

(I don't understand how you plotted a symmetric impulse response (time domain) for Butterworth filters; their impulse response is causal and asymmetric in general.)

Comment: thanks, the butterworth filter is applied twice, once in forward direction and once after the time series is reversed, so that overall there is zero phase change and order of the filter is effectively twice